# inserting data to the google appengine's database

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-datastore

For my website I wanted to store the IP address of every visitor.I had been doing this with derby+Tomcat,but I don't know how to do this with google appengine. How can I insert data to appengine's database ? I mean how do I connect to its database.

I have no idea how to do this.

*NOTE :* It will be great if somebody answers me with some code,that tells me how to connect to the database to start sending queries.

Answer (score 1):

The link below is really a good introduction guide. You don't have to understand at all how Google App Engine datastore works to be able to store / retrieve data + there is a very active community to support you.

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to select your interface for connecting to the GAE datastore. Your choices include:

- the GAE low-level datastore API
- JPA
- JDO
- Objectify
- Twig

(apologies to any I have missed). Then you need to study the relevant documentation to find out how to use your selected interface.

Answer (score 0):

Google app engine's datastore is a bit strange when comparing with other sql-databases. It needs quite a lot of learning.

But if you are not really interested in it, then you can try google's fusion tables. Its free and also it has SQL-like query mechanism.

It needs a slighter modification to your existing application. Signup for fusion tables then store and access your data through Fusion table API in App Engine.